# How to override InputBase<T> Value in Blazor, in order to validate

Tags: c#, inheritance, components, blazor

I am trying to build a new Blazor input component, which inherits from InputBase, so that I can provide a form input field for selecting employees in an organisation. I need to provide the ability to limit the input to a single person or allow multiple selections, dependant on use case.

The input component I am building accepts a List of type "Employee", which is a class built specifically for our employee dataset. I have setup a Boolean value to denote if multi-selection should be allowed. However, I can't intercept the change in the Value to stop additional people being added if it should be limited to a single selection.

I have tried the following override of the InputBase Value property:

---

```
    new public List<Employee> Value
    {
        get
        {
            return CurrentValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!Multiselect)
            {
                CurrentValue = value.Take(1).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                CurrentValue = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Due to having a List binding I have overridden the FormatValueAsString and TryParseValueFromString so that the email addresses can be seen in an input field, as part of the component. I can add multi-selection logic into these functions, however they still allow the Value to end up with multiple in, though the string shown in the UI will only contain one.

**EDIT:**
Adding more code as requested.

.razor file:

```
@inherits InputBase<List<Employee>>
@using Project.Models.Employee

<div class="InputEmployee">
    <input class="InputEmployee" @bind="CurrentValueAsString" type="text" />
    <i class="oi oi-person" @onclick="() => openSearch()"></i>
</div>
<div class="InputEmployeeSearch @(displaySearch ? "": " collapse")" @onblur="() => toggleSearch()" id="searchInput">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="searchInput">
            <input @bind-Value="searchString" @bind-Value:event="oninput" placeholder="Search by name, email address, employee number" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
    @if (activeSearch)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="searchActive">
                Searching...
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    @if (foundEmployees != null && foundEmployees.Any())
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="searchResults">
                @foreach (Employee employee in foundEmployees)
                {
                    <div class="employeeResult" @onclick="() => select(employee)">
                        @employee.DisplayName
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    @if (errorMessage != null)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="searchError">
                @errorMessage
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

.razor.cs file:

```
using Project.Models.Employee;
using Project.Services.Employee;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace Project.Components
{
    public partial class InputEmployee : InputBase<List<Employee>>
    {
        [Inject]
        private IEmployeeDataService EmployeeDataService { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public int Debounce { get; set; } = 500;
        [Parameter]
        public int MaximumResults { get; set; } = 10;
        [Parameter]
        public int MinimumLength { get; set; } = 4;
        [Parameter]
        public bool Multiselect { get; set; } = false;
        new public List<Employee> Value
        {
            get
            {
                return CurrentValue;
            }
            set
            {
                if (!Multiselect)
                {
                    CurrentValue = value.Take(1).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    CurrentValue = value;
                }
            }
        }

        private string currentValueOverlay = "";
        private bool activeSearch = false;
        private bool displaySearch = false;
        private Timer debounceTimer;
        private string searchString
        {
            get
            {
                return searchText;
            }

            set
            {
                searchText = value;

                if (value.Length == 0)
                {
                    debounceTimer.Stop();
                    activeSearch = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    debounceTimer.Stop();
                    debounceTimer.Start();
                    activeSearch = true;
                }
            }
        }
        private string searchText = "";
        private string errorMessage;
        private List<Employee> foundEmployees;

        protected override void OnParametersSet()
        {
            base.OnParametersSet();
            debounceTimer = new Timer();
            debounceTimer.Interval = Debounce;
            debounceTimer.AutoReset = false;
            debounceTimer.Elapsed += search;
        }

        protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out List<Employee> result, out string validationErrorMessage)
        {
            result = new List<Employee>();
            validationErrorMessage = null;

            string[] valueArray = value.Split(";");
            List<Employee> output = new List<Employee>();

            foreach (string employeeEmail in valueArray)
            {
                try
                {
                    Employee employee = Task.Run(async () => await EmployeeDataService.FindEmployeesAsync(employeeEmail.Trim())).Result.FirstOrDefault();

                    if (employee != null)
                    {
                        output.Add(employee);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    validationErrorMessage = $"User \"{employeeEmail}\" was not found.";
                }
            }

            result = output;
            return true;
        }

        protected override string FormatValueAsString(List<Employee> employees)
        {
            string employeeString = "";

            if (employees.Any() && employees.FirstOrDefault() != null)
            {
                employeeString = String.Join("; ", employees.Select(x => x.Email).ToArray());
            }

            return employeeString;
        }

        private async void toggleSearch()
        {
            displaySearch = !displaySearch;

            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        }

        private void openSearch()
        {
            foundEmployees = new List<Employee>();

            if (searchString.Length >= MinimumLength)
            {
                search(null, null);
            }

            toggleSearch();
        }

#nullable enable
        private async void search(Object? source, ElapsedEventArgs? e)
        {
            errorMessage = null;
            foundEmployees = null;
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);

            if (int.TryParse(searchString, out int i))
            {
                if (searchString.Length == 9)
                {
                    List<string> searchList = new List<string>();
                    searchList.Add(searchString);
                    foundEmployees = (await EmployeeDataService.GetEmployeesAsync(searchList)).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    updateError($"Searching by employee number requires the full number.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (searchString.Length < MinimumLength)
                {
                    updateError($"You must enter at least {MinimumLength} characters of their name or email address.");
                }
                else
                {
                    foundEmployees = (await EmployeeDataService.FindEmployeesAsync(searchString)).Take(MaximumResults).ToList();
                }
            }

            if (foundEmployees != null && !foundEmployees.Any())
            {
                updateError($"No employees found matching \"{searchString}\".");
            }

            activeSearch = false;
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        }

        private async void updateError(string message)
        {
            activeSearch = false;
            errorMessage = message;
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        }

        private void select(Employee employee)
        {
            Value.Add(employee);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing code for your custom input control and the HTML for it?

Comment: The only workaround I found at the moment is to copy the source code of InputBase.cs into a custom class InputBaseVirtual.cs and then make the Value property virtual. Later, inherit from this other class.

Answer (score 2):

To add validation messages in your custom control you can override `TryParseValueFromString` method on the `InputBase` and write as following:

```cs
protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out TValue result, out string validationErrorMessage)
{
    if (typeof(TValue) == typeof(string))
    {
        result = (TValue)(object)value;
        validationErrorMessage = null;
        return true;
    }
    else if (typeof(TValue).IsEnum)
    {
        var success = BindConverter.TryConvertTo<TValue>(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out var parsedValue);
        if (success)
        {
            result = parsedValue;
            validationErrorMessage = null;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = default;
            validationErrorMessage = $"The {FieldIdentifier.FieldName} field is not valid.";
            return false;
        }
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException($"{GetType()} does not support the type '{typeof(TValue)}'.");
}
```

This is taken from and has more details on [this blog](https://chrissainty.com/building-custom-input-components-for-blazor-using-inputbase#binding-to-additional-types) from Chris Sainty.

Comment: Adding my logic into these methods, does show the correct value in the text box. However, the underlying value of the input component still contains many employees which is what will get saved back to the database.

I need to manage the component Value to ensure it is always correct.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you want to limit this method

```cs
private void select(Employee employee)
{
  if (MultiSelect)
  {
    Value.Add(employee);
  }
  else
  { 
    Value = new List<Employee> { employee };
  }
}
```

Comment: I have considered this, but then I'd need to add the validation to anywhere that interacts with Value, such as in the string conversion methods as well. There must be a way to track Value (which I believe is the lowest level of the component data storage) and do the validation there.